# Django production get Service Unavailable

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, deployment

I'm trying to setup my app with django but unfortunately I can't I just got a Service Unavailable message.

I'm using vestacp

The apache configuration works in the same ubuntu 14 without vestacp but using vestacp I can not achieve to work.

**settings.py**

```
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


it suppose to work using "*"
```

**apache2.conf**

```
<VirtualHost 172.31.2.45:80>

    ServerName ip-172-31-2-45.us-west-1.compute.internal
    ServerAlias www.ip-172-31-2-45.us-west-1.compute.internal
    ServerAdmin info@ip-172-31-2-45.us-west-1.compute.internal
    DocumentRoot /home/admin/web/ip-172-31-2-45.us-west-1.compute.internal/public_html
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/admin/web/ip-172-31-2-45.us-west-1.compute.internal/cgi-bin/
    Alias /vstats/ /home/admin/web/ip-172-31-2-45.us-west-1.compute.internal/stats/
    Alias /error/ /home/admin/web/ip-172-31-2-45.us-west-1.compute.internal/document_errors/
    #SuexecUserGroup admin admin
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/ip-172-31-2-45.us-west-1.compute.internal.bytes bytes
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/ip-172-31-2-45.us-west-1.compute.internal.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domains/ip-172-31-2-45.us-west-1.compute.internal.error.log
    <Directory /home/admin/web/ip-172-31-2-45.us-west-1.compute.internal/public_html>
        AllowOverride All
        Options +Includes -Indexes +ExecCGI
        php_admin_value open_basedir /home/admin/web/ip-172-31-2-45.us-west-1.compute.internal/public_html:/home/admin/tmp
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /home/admin/tmp
        php_admin_value session.save_path /home/admin/tmp
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/admin/web/ip-172-31-2-45.us-west-1.compute.internal/stats>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RMode config
        RUidGid admin admin
        RGroups www-data
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule itk.c>
        AssignUserID admin admin
    </IfModule>

    IncludeOptional /home/admin/conf/web/apache2.ip-172-31-2-45.us-west-1.compute.internal.conf*

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.31.2.45:80>

    ServerName mensajeriadf.com
    ServerAlias www.mensajeriadf.com
    ServerAdmin info@mensajeriadf.com

    DocumentRoot /home/admin/web/mensajeriadf.com/public_html

       WSGIDaemonProcess sampleapp python-path=/var/www/sampleapp/sampleapp:/var/www/sampleapp/env/python2.7/site-packages
       WSGIProcessGroup sampleapp
       WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/sampleapp/sampleapp/sampleapp/wsgi.py

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/admin/web/mensajeriadf.com/cgi-bin/
    Alias /vstats/ /home/admin/web/mensajeriadf.com/stats/
    Alias /error/ /home/admin/web/mensajeriadf.com/document_errors/
    #SuexecUserGroup admin admin
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/mensajeriadf.com.bytes bytes
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/mensajeriadf.com.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domains/mensajeriadf.com.error.log
    <Directory /home/admin/web/mensajeriadf.com/public_html>
        AllowOverride All
        Options +Includes -Indexes +ExecCGI
        php_admin_value open_basedir /home/admin/web/mensajeriadf.com/public_html:/home/admin/tmp
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /home/admin/tmp
        php_admin_value session.save_path /home/admin/tmp
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/admin/web/mensajeriadf.com/stats>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RMode config
        RUidGid admin admin
        RGroups www-data
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule itk.c>
        AssignUserID admin admin
    </IfModule>

    IncludeOptional /home/admin/conf/web/apache2.mensajeriadf.com.conf*

</VirtualHost>
```

If I run the server as runserver it works fine, the problem is with apache I think, I have installed wsgi mod and it is enable, I do not know i'm doing bad.

I will really appreciate any help. I have days with this.
Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Please add the relevant part of apache's error log. Make sure you have a suitable log level.